# Can ParquetWriter or AvroParquetWriter store the schema separately?

Tags: hadoop, avro, parquet

Do you know, can ParquetWriter or AvroParquetWriter store the schema separately without data?

Now schema is written into parquet file:

```
AvroParquetWriter.Builder builder = AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(new Path(file.getName()))
            .withSchema(payload.getSchema())
            .build90;
```

Do you know is possible write only data without schema into parquet file?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@ЭльфияВалиева.  No, the parquet metadata (schema) in the footer is necessary to provide parquet readers the necessary schema to read the parquet data.